# xp_cmdshell using problem (SQL Server 2008 R2)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a problem with `xp_cmdshell`; my SQL Server version is:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP2)-10.50.4000.0(X64)
```

Example of problem: when I try to execute this command:

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'echo Hello> D:\te.txt'
```

I get this error :

> The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'xp_cmdshell', database 'mssqlsystemresource', schema 'sys'.

So I tried this :

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON xp_cmdshell TO [user];
```

but it's still not working!

These are the user permissions in the database:

```
CREATE TABLE
CREATE VIEW
CREATE PROCEDURE
CREATE FUNCTION
CREATE RULE
CREATE DEFAULT
BACKUP DATABASE
BACKUP LOG
CREATE TYPE
CREATE ASSEMBLY
CREATE XML SCHEMA COLLECTION
CREATE SCHEMA
CREATE SYNONYM
CREATE AGGREGATE
CREATE ROLE
CREATE MESSAGE TYPE
CREATE SERVICE
CREATE CONTRACT
CREATE REMOTE SERVICE BINDING
CREATE ROUTE
CREATE QUEUE
CREATE SYMMETRIC KEY
CREATE ASYMMETRIC KEY
CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG
CREATE CERTIFICATE
CREATE DATABASE DDL EVENT NOTIFICATION
CONNECT
CONNECT REPLICATION
CHECKPOINT
SUBSCRIBE QUERY NOTIFICATIONS
AUTHENTICATE
SHOWPLAN
ALTER ANY USER
ALTER ANY ROLE
ALTER ANY APPLICATION ROLE
ALTER ANY SCHEMA
ALTER ANY ASSEMBLY
ALTER ANY DATASPACE
ALTER ANY MESSAGE TYPE
ALTER ANY CONTRACT
ALTER ANY SERVICE
ALTER ANY REMOTE SERVICE BINDING
ALTER ANY ROUTE
ALTER ANY FULLTEXT CATALOG
ALTER ANY SYMMETRIC KEY
ALTER ANY ASYMMETRIC KEY
ALTER ANY CERTIFICATE
SELECT
INSERT
UPDATE
DELETE
REFERENCES
EXECUTE
ALTER ANY DATABASE DDL TRIGGER
ALTER ANY DATABASE EVENT NOTIFICATION
ALTER ANY DATABASE AUDIT
VIEW DATABASE STATE
VIEW DEFINITION
TAKE OWNERSHIP
ALTER
CONTROL
```

Comment: It would generally be a Bad Idea to be using xp_cmdshell in an ASP.NET application.

Comment: Unless you are a `sysadmin` you cannot use `xp_cmdshell`.

Comment: And to add, don't grant your application `sysadmin` privileges.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I know it’s bad idea , i’m working on my localhost & it’s very necessary for me to complete my research i need a way to solve this how to bypass that

Comment: @Larnu I have sysadmin permissions on the database but not on the server..

Comment: If you need to write a file called `te.txt` use the application itself to do so; not SQL Server. And you having `sysadmin` doesn't change that the application doesn't (and shouldn't).

Comment: @Larnu I can do that , but it’s not what i want , as i said before i need a way to bypass the permissions or something like that to use the xp_cmdshell

Answer (score 1):

The procedure to enable a non sysadmin to run xp_cmdshell is special, and documented here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/xp-cmdshell-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

In addition to granting permission you need to provision a least-privilege windows user and configure it as the xp_cmdshell proxy account.

Comment: I tried this already , this is the result :                                                                                                    The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'sp_xp_cmdshell_proxy_account', database 'mssqlsystemresource', schema 'sys'.

Comment: Obviously a sysadmin and Windows Administrator are needed to perform those steps.